# Content-MD5 header in http PUT request, what should the response be?

Tags: http

Context - Implementing HTTP server, I expect Content-MD5 in case server receives a POST/PUT requests.

Question is, how to handle MD5 mismatch, I presume because MD5 didn't match data isn't valid, user must retry sending data again. What would be right status code in http response to be sent so that browsers indicate the user that resource sent has not been consumed and user must retry sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Content-MD5 is deprecated (see https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#changes.from.rfc.2616). I wouldn't expect it to be sent in practice.
2. For an alternative, see https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-httpbis-digest-headers-04.html. That spec is still under development, so if you have questions/suggestions, I'd recommend to ask over on the HTTPBIS mailing list.